# checking whether a point is above or below a slope

Tags: geometry

I want to know if points are located below or above  a given line with slope y=m*x+c where the x and the y are the coordinate location .
i don't want to check if not on the line itself .

Answer (score 0):

Points $P=(x_P,y_p)$ with $ y_P>mx_p+c$ are above the line and points with $ y_P<mx_p+c$ are below the line.

Comment: okay thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line parallel to the given line from $(x_1,y_1) $(points whose position w.r.t. given line (above or below ) is to be determined ) and let it cut y-axis at

$ y = Y  = (y_1 - m x_1) $

If $  Y > c, $ then the point is above and

if $  Y < c $ then the point is below the given line.